# Loop through directory

Tags: php

I'm trying to use PHP to bring in every image from a specific directory and turn them into HTML objects by wrapping some markup around them.

Right now I am just trying to get the images on the page. In the future I would also like to bring in a text file that has the same file name as the image(slide#4.jpg and slide#4.txt).

This is what I have so far.

```
<?php

    $dir = "includes/pages/products/*.jpg";

    $images = glob( $dir );

    foreach( $images as $image ):
        $file = basename($image);
        $file = basename($image, ".jpg");
        echo "<div class='"prod-cont"'>" . "<h4>" . $file . "</h4>" . "<img src'" . $image "' />" . "</div>";
    endforeach;
?>
```

I'm not having much luck getting this going, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do not forget `htmlspecialchars()` for interesting filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the second `$file =` line, and make sure you're generating correct HTML.

```
echo "<div class='prod-cont'><h4>".$file."</h4><img src='".$image."' /></div>";
```

Comment: I tried this but it still doesnt work.  It gives me;   Invalid argument supplied for foreach()